# argument passing in pthread_creation

Tags: c++, c

I am learning how to work with pthread functions.
Here i want to create a thread using pthread_create and calculate the average of some numbers with it.
( a 0 at the end of the number sequence shows it has finished)

This is what I've written so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stack>
#include<pthread.h>

using namespace std;


void *Thread1(void*argument)  
{
printf("in Thread1\n");

int sum=0;
int count=0;
stack<int> numbers;
(stack<int>) numbers = *((stack<int>*) argument);
int size = numbers.size();


while(numbers.size()!=0)
{

sum=sum+numbers.top();
count=count+1;
numbers.pop();
}

int result= sum / count;
printf("Average is :");
printf("%d",result);

pthread_exit(0);

}


int main(void)
{
printf("Enter your numbers\n");

int num;
stack<int> numStack;
scanf("%d",&num);
numStack.push(num);

while( num!=0)
{
scanf("%d",&num);

numStack.push(num);
}

numStack.pop();
pthread_t myThread;
int ret;

ret=pthread_create(&myThread,NULL,Thread1,&numStack); 

if (ret<0)
   printf("Thread Creation Failed\n");


pthread_join(myThread,NULL);
return 0;
}
```

when i get the size of my stack in main and check it by printing it, it's correct but when i do the same in the Thread1 function the size is 0.  Therefore i get the

```
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

error.

Why the size of my stack turns into 0?  How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
(stack<int>) numbers = *((stack<int>*) argument);
```

cast is the root of the zero size set. The first C-Type cast creates a temporary unnamed object as a copy of numbers which vanishes after assignment. `numbers` is never changed. Make it:

```
numbers = *((stack<int>*) argument);
```

Comment: In addition, OP may want to call `exit` if `pthread_create` fails and use floating point type to calculate average as it's currently uses integer division.